# I want to delete permanently xcode select (not xcode)

Tags: xcode

I have some question that I didn't install xcode.app but in my mac there is xcode-select exist.

there is no problem while now but when i install some npm module there is error that `no version xcode or CTL`.

but as i say xcode-select is exist in my mac and when i typing `xcode-select -v` version is 2373.

so i think xcode-select is problem, decide to remove xcode-select.

As many people say `delete ~/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` so delete it.

but typing `xcode-select -v` after delete directory there is still version 2373 is printed.

how can i delete permanently xcode-select? anyone know about this problem please give me opinion!

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

self answer, going to apple download center and download dmg file for xcode command line tools. it is most fast way to solve this issue.